# Touch sensors not working after installing 16.04 on Toshiba satellite p755-s5260

Tags: 16.04, toshiba-satellite

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Toshiba Satellite P755-S5260 but the touch sensors are not functioning except the volume sensor.

On 14.04 LTS it was working fine.

How can I make them function as they did in 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. My Wifi adapter sensors are working perfectly now. I just put my driver's process in the `blacklist.conf` located at `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

For toshiba Intel adapter the process is `toshiba_acpi`

At the end of `blocklist.conf` write:
`blacklist toshiba_acpi`